# Applying fields parsing in perl

Tags: perl

Perl one-liners includes the following example:

```
$ls -l | perl -lane 'print "$F[7] $F[1]"'
 106576
14:12 3
14:12 3
14:12 3
09:45 3
```

When trying to apply that pattern to parsing a simple file according to:

```
head simhash.txt | perl -nela  'print "$F[1]"'
```

The following error occurs:

```
Can't open print "$F[1]": No such file or directory.
```

What is missing/incorrect here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprise (to me at least) .. the order of the options

```
-lane
```

instead of

```
-nela
```

*does* matter.  Changing the command to

```
head simhash.txt | perl -lane  'print "$F[1]"'
```

gives the expected output.

Comment: Note that `-alne`, `-anle`, `-lane`, `-lnae`, `-nale`, and `-nlae` would all work fine. This is not unique to perl, it's true of most *nix utilities that have a flag with a required argument.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  y - got it.